# Regex to find the latest merged branch name

Tags: regex, git, grep, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find the name of the latest branch that was merged in master branch. all the other branch except master was named in a pattern `testBranch/<version of release>`

So I use this command to grab the whole list of branch:

```
git branch -a --merged master
outputs: 
 remotes/origin/testBranch/1.2.0
 remotes/origin/testBranch/1.1.0
 remotes/origin/master
```

then was thinking a regex to get the latest branch name using 'grep'. For example:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep <pattern>
```

I have tested in regex tester online with this:

```
(origin\/testBranch\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+){1}
(origin\/testBranch\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)*?
```

Cant seem to get it to work. In some other trial i got both line:

```
remotes/origin/testBranch/1.2.0
remotes/origin/testBranch/1.1.0
```

What i need is to output just the very first occurrence of:

```
remotes/origin/testBranch/<release version>
So in above example, should output: 
remotes/origin/testBranch/1.2.0
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a regex? `git branch -a --merged master |grep remote|head -1` ?

Comment: thats awesome. this outputs: remotes/origin/testBranch/1.2.0. Is there any way to get only: origin/testBranch/1.2.0? without 'remote'. Also could you please explain the answer. Thank you

Comment: added as an answer, hopefully with an understandable explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than perform a complex regular expression, you might be better off getting the top most line of the output, e.g.:

```
git branch -a --merged master | head -1
```

if you only want to get the merged remote branches, you can use grep https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html to extract just the remote branches:

```
git branch -a --merged master | grep -i remote | head -1
```

if you're looking at extracting specific information from the line, e.g. everything after "remotes/" or even after "origin/" you can use either `awk` or `sed` to remove words that you don't want, e.g.:

```
git branch -a --merged master | grep -i remote | sed 's/remotes\///;s/origin\///' | head -1
```

or possibly neater, with awk:

```
git branch -a --merged master | awk '/remote/ {gsub("(remotes|origin)/",""); print; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU `sort`:

```
git branch -a --merged master | sort -Vr | head -n 1
```

Output:

```
 remotes/origin/testBranch/1.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were wanting to use a regular expression, you could use an expression like this `(remotes\/origin\/testBranch\/\d\.\d\.\d)` and that will match only the first occurrence. Referring to jad's answer, you could also just use `git branch -a --merged master |grep remote|head -1` instead of regex.